# Call a Win32 DLL into netcoreapp test project

Tags: c#, winapi, dll, .net-core

I have an "old" win32 dll that I need to load in my unit test/integration test project to do some test processing.

This dll is referenced simply as

```
  private static extern ushort SSV_InitTrace(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string fileName,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string mode,
        ushort module, byte level);
```

This is working into a "classical" xUnit test project that run on win32 platform.
However, in my integrations tests, I need to load a bunch of netcore assemblies coming from my solution. 
I define my project.json like this :

```
 "dependencies": {
  "xunit": "2.2.0-beta2-build3300",
  "CommonTools": "1.0.0",
  "FluentAssertions": "4.6.1",
  "SESAMEngineFacturation": "1.0.0",
  "Moq": "4.6.25-alpha",
  "DALCore": "1.0.0",
  "BusinessCore": "1.0.0",
  "dotnet-test-xunit": "2.2.0-preview2-build1029",
  "System.Reflection.Extensions": "4.0.1",
  "SESAMReglementaire": "1.0.0-*",
  "SESAMReglementaire.Tests": "1.0.0-*",
  "System.Runtime.InteropServices": "4.1.0",
  "System.Linq.Expressions": "4.1.0"
 },
"frameworks": {
  "netcoreapp1.0": {
    "dependencies": {
     "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.0"
    },
    "System.Reflection.TypeExtensions": "4.1.0",
    "System.Diagnostics.TraceSource": "4.0.0"
  },
  "imports": [
    "dnxcore50",
    "portable-net45+win81"
  ]
 }
}
```

When I hit my dllimport, I encounter a badImageFormatException.
How can I force my netcoreApp to run in win32 mode ? 
I already tried to set

```
  "buildOptions": { "platform": "x86" }
```

into the netcoreapp section, but if I do that, tests doesn't appears anymore into VS Test Explorer.

How can I manager to make this run ?